# reload view / data after json request is completed in iOS Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a `SectionsData.swift` file where I get some data from a get http request:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class SectionsData {
    func getSectionsFromData() -> [Section] {
        var sectionsArray = [Section]()

        let animals = Section(title: "Animals", objects:  ["Cats", "Dogs", "Lions", "Birds"], place: "Jungle")
        let vehicles = Section(title: "Vehicles", objects: ["Cars", "Bicycle"], place: "Road")
        let movies = Section(title: "Movies", objects: ["Sound", "Music"], place: "Cinema")

        sectionsArray.append(animals)
        sectionsArray.append(vehicles)
        sectionsArray.append(movies)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com")
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    var openEvents = Section(title: "Events", objects: [], place: "Rooms")
                    for index in 0...9 {
                        let eventName = JSON["events"]!![index]["name"]! as! String
                        openEvents.items.append(eventName)
                    }

                    sectionsArray.append(openEvents)

                }
        }

        return sectionsArray
    }
}
```

And in the `ViewController.swift` file, I'm trying to reload the view after the JSON request is complete:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sections: [Section] = SectionsData().getSectionsFromData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].heading
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].items.count 
    }
    ...
```

Currently, I only see the static data with table view sections for "Animals", "Vehicles" and "Movies" and no "Events" section.

I believe I will need to reload the view somewhere. How can I do so?

Comment: If it's just updating the data in your TableView, try self.tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, inside your `getSectionsFromData()` you're calling an asynchronously call to `Alamofire.request()` which will not be executed in due time for the `sectionsArray` to have the returned data. You're in fact returning the static array from `getSectionsFromData`.

To fix this you could use a callback in the `getSectionsFromData()`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate     {    

    var sections: [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SecionsData().getSectionsFromData({
            sections in

            self.sections = sections

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}

class SectionsData {

    func getSectionsFromData(callback: (sections: [Section]) -> ()) {

        var sectionsArray = [Section]()

        let animals = Section(title: "Animals", objects:  ["Cats", "Dogs", "Lions", "Birds"], place: "Jungle")
        let vehicles = Section(title: "Vehicles", objects: ["Cars", "Bicycle"], place: "Road")
        let movies = Section(title: "Movies", objects: ["Sound", "Music"], place: "Cinema")

        sectionsArray.append(animals)
        sectionsArray.append(vehicles)
        sectionsArray.append(movies)


        Alamofire.request(.Get, "https://example.com")
            .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                var openEvents = Section(title: "Events", objects: [], place: "Rooms")
                for index in 0...9 {
                    let eventName = JSON["events"]!![index]["name"]! as! String
                    openEvents.items.append(eventName)
                }

                sectionsArray.append(openEvents)
            }

            // This will pass the sections with or without any fetched data into the callback
            callback(sections: sectionsArray)
        }
    }
}
```

[Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)